# LaTeX math as an image of a specific size

Tags: equations, standalone, png, dvi

I know very little about TeX and LaTeX, but I often encounter strings containing markup described as LaTeX, because various tools, including MathJax, SymPy and Apple's Grapher, use LaTeX as a lingua franca for math.  A user can often right-click on a nicely-formatted equation in a GUI and get a representation of it "as LaTeX" or call a method in a script and get a string described as containing "LaTeX markup".   (I don't know if I'm using the correct terminology.)

I'm trying to take such a string and use automation to turn it into an image of a specific size (625 x 465 pixels as an example) with the equation expanded or shrunk to fit the image, or, failing that, at least centered.

I'm programmatically creating `.tex` files, using `latex` to compile to DVI, then using `dvipng` to convert to PNG.  I have tried over 30 permutations of the various suggestions I've read on Stack Exchange.  I've tried document classes including `standalone`, `article`, `report` and `minimal`.  I've tried packages including `graphicx`, `preview` and `geometry`.  I've tried commands including `resizebox`, `vspace`, `topskip`, `centering` and `noindent`.  I've tried `dvipng` options `-T` and `-D`.

The results I get are never quite right:

Wrong size:
[image: Wrong size]

Correct size, but oddly aligned:
[image: Correct size, but oddly aligned]

Others are the correct size but blank (especially using `standalone` with options other than `preview`).

How can I produce images of the specified size that look right?  Does anyone know a combination of a TeX document template into which I can insert the math markup, and a dvipng command that will convert it correctly?

I am running on Debian.  `latex --version` reports `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)`.  `dvipng --version` reports `dvipng 1.14`.

an example latex command:

```
latex -halt-on-error -interaction batchmode -output-directory /data/notebooks/2016-09-13T17:41:22.181658_typesetting /data/notebooks/2016-09-13T17:41:22.181658_typesetting/foo21.tex
```

an example dvipng command:

```
dvipng -T 6.25in,4.65in -z 9 -bg gray 0.80 -o /data/notebooks/2016-09-13T17:41:22.181658_typesetting/foo21.png /data/notebooks/2016-09-13T17:41:22.181658_typesetting/foo21.dvi
```

I've been keeping a catalog of attempts in a Jupyter notebook.  If necessary, maybe I could put all 31 (and counting) attempts on a Gist or something, with the `.tex` files, `latex` commands, `dvipng` commands, and result images.

Comment: consider using package geometry to specify the output page dimensions. You need also that your TeX (LaTeX?) snippet produces no page number. However with dvipng I think it is not possible to get png images including the information of absolute pixel size. But others will correct me if needed.

Comment: the following thread http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/dvipng/2012-10/msg00000.html may be relevant. But perhaps things have changed since 2012.

Comment: actually the thread may be irrelevant ; have you tried `-T="tight"` or something like that with `dvipng` (and page dimensions -- and margins etc -- set by package geometry) ?

Comment: Is the issue that the png file is the wrong size, or then reincluding it in another document produces the wrong size?  I am confused.

Comment: I too don't understand the problem. Is the dvi file ok? Wouldn't producing a pdf and then converting to png being a proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the easiest way to get what I wanted was to use the `preview` package with the `tightpage` option in the `.tex` file, and use the `convert` command from ImageMagick to expand the image.

This is the template I use for the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[active,displaymath,textmath,tightpage]{preview}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$ 
% MATH GOES HERE
$
\end{document}
```

Some of the packages and options might be unnecessary, but the above works for me.

Then I run this `latex` command (substitute your working directory for `/bar`):

```
latex -halt-on-error -interaction batchmode -output-directory /bar /bar/foo.tex
```

Then this `dvipng` command (I have to choose an appropriate value for the `-D` option manually):

```
dvipng -D 225 -z 9 -bg white -o /bar/foo.png /bar/foo.dvi
```

Then this `convert` command:

```
convert /bar/foo.png -background white -gravity center -extent 625x465 /bar/foo_resized.png
```

To get the necessary tools installed I ran:

```
apt-get install texlive
apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
apt-get install dvipng
apt-get install imagemagick
```